Deleting a question that has an answer
Until recently there was a policy that a (possibly weak) question should not be deleted, once a well formulated answer had been posted. The reasoning was that deleting the question also causes the answer to be deleted. This would be unfair to the person who answered the question. He or she had invested time and energy in formulating his/her answer. It was also argued that deleting the (possibly weak) question would deprive the math community of a valuable answer.
Now there is a new policy. A weak post can be deleted by a moderator, even if it had already been answered. This completely contradicts the previous policy. Apparently the arguments for the previous policy are now considered invalid.
Why should anyone bother to answer a (fairly weak) question, and thereby risk that the (good) answer gets deleted by a moderator?

I do not think that you have correctly understood the policy.  The general policy is that the asker of a question should not delete their question immediately after getting an answer.  There has never been any policy which prevents other users from closing and/or deleting off-topic, duplicate, or low-quality questions, whether or not they have been answered.

The position that good answers should not be deleted has been strongly advocated by a number of users over the years. I'm not sure those users have ever been in the majority, and I'm quite sure their position has never risen to the level of "policy". Maybe, M. Wind, you could present evidence to support your assertion. In any event, there is nothing new about the EOQS, which holds that users should be discouraged from answering questions that aren't up to site standards, and, for better or worse, EOQS is policy.

Insomuch as there is an official policy (there isn't, really), it is that askers should not delete a question they have asked immediately after getting an answer.  The official reason for this is that it takes time to write a good answer and the answer may be useful to other users---hence unilaterally deleting a question you have asked, once it has an answer, is disrespectful to the person who took the time to answer your question, and to potential future readers.  A single user who has not earned the community's trust really oughtn't have that power.
I also suspect that there is an element of "don't use Math SE to cheat" which informs this policy.  I think that many users have the suspicion that immediate deletion is a sign that the asker has, perhaps, asked a question in an attempt to cheat on some kind of assessment, and that deleting that question is an attempt to cover their tracks.  While this should not be relevant to moderation here, I would not be surprised if this factors into some people's thinking with respect to quick deletion by the asker.
This is a completely distinct case from a question being deleted by other users, whether or not the question has been answered.  If five users vote to delete a question (or if a moderator elects to delete a question), that is part of the usual content moderation of the site, and has nothing to do with any of the above discussion.
